# How can we create payruns without timesheet on xero?

Tags: laravel, xero-api

I am needed to create pay runs on xero. I have created employees on xero successfully, i don't know how to create payruns without timesheet. How can we send employees hours to xero. Have a look on the payload i send to create payruns on xero.

> [{ "PayrollCalendarID":"d99590f1-670d-4bc1-947c-a6cac36e31d2","PayRunPeriodStartDate":"/Date(1689379200000+0000)/","PaymentDate":"/Date(1690588800000+0000)/","Wages":4035.00,"Deductions":0.00,"Tax":1062.00,"Super":201.15,"Reimbursement":0.00,"NetPay":2973.00,"PayRunStatus":"POSTED","UpdatedDateUTC":"/Date(1689136195000+0000)/","Employees":[{"EmployeeID":"2643a7cd-7753-4533-b7a4-49f27cbbde57","Hours":20}]
> }]

Any help/suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks